where to specify a version number for openapi when calling external plugin using ImportPluginFromOpenApiAsync
I am trying to invoke semantic kernel plugin using OpenAPI call
var plugin = await kernel.ImportPluginFromOpenApiAsync(
      name,
      endpoint,
      new OpenApiFunctionExecutionParameters(httpClient));

var arguments = new KernelArguments
{
    ["param1"] = "..."
};

await plugin[functionName].InvokeAsync(kernel, arguments);

I am getting the following error:
Message: 
Microsoft.OpenApi.Readers.Exceptions.OpenApiUnsupportedSpecVersionException : OpenAPI specification version '' is not supported.

Where should the version number be specified (say as v3.0.0), is it appsettings.json of the plugin project?
 "aiPlugin": {
   "schemaVersion": "v1",
   "nameForModel": "",
   "nameForHuman": "",
   "descriptionForModel": "",
   "descriptionForHuman": "",
   "auth": {
     "type": "none"
   },
   "api": {
     "type": "openapi",
     "url": "{url}/swagger.json",
   }, 

i tried adding to api section the following
openapi: 3.0.0

but it made no difference - still displayed as empty as '' from the error message.
Thank you

i rushed with the question ;~(
the answer as to use the correct url with latest openapi version
http://localhost:7071/openapi/v3.json

the answer was just to use the right url:
http://localhost:7071/openapi/v3.json
